# Mocking AWS Go SSM GetParameter call

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, go

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/example/service/dynamodb/unitTest/unitTest_test.go), but using it to mock the SSM GetParameter call instead.
All I want to do is to send the value of `inputParameter` and verify that the output is the value of `outputParameter`.

When I run a `go test`, it just throws the error that I defined, but not sure why. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my function:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ssm"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ssm/ssmiface"

)

type AWS struct {
        Config  *aws.Config
        Session *session.Session
        SSM     ssmiface.SSMAPI
}



func (self *AWS) GetSSMValue(SSMPath string) string {
        req, err := self.SSM.GetParameter(&ssm.GetParameterInput{
                Name:           aws.String(SSMPath),
                WithDecryption: aws.Bool(false),
        })
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("Unable to retrieve value: ", err)
        }
        SSMValue := *req.Parameter.Value

        return SSMValue
}


func main() {
        Aws := new(AWS)
        Aws.Config = &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2")}
        Aws.Session, _ = session.NewSession(Aws.Config)

        ssmsvc := ssm.New(Aws.Session)
        Aws.SSM = ssmiface.SSMAPI(ssmsvc)

        inputParam := "/path/to/my/parameter"
        myValue := Aws.GetSSMValue(inputParam)
        fmt.Println(myValue)

}
```

and my test:

```
package main

import (
        "errors"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ssm"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ssm/ssmiface"
        "testing"
)

type mockSSM struct {
        ssmiface.SSMAPI
        response string
        err  error
}

func (sp *mockSSM) GetParameter(input *ssm.GetParameterInput) (*ssm.GetParameterOutput, error) {
        output := new(ssm.GetParameterOutput)
        return output, sp.err

}

func TestGetSSMValue(t *testing.T) {
        inputParameter := "path/to/my/test"
        outputParameter := "MyTestOutput"
        retriever := new(AWS)
        retriever.SSM = &mockSSM{
                response: outputParameter,
                err:  errors.New("my custom error"),
        }
        if actualValue := retriever.GetSSMValue(inputParameter); actualValue != outputParameter {
                t.Errorf("Expected %q but got %q", outputParameter, actualValue)
        }

}
```

Comment: You're setting a non-nil error in the mocked implementation, and it looks like the implementation is interpreting as (correctly) an error condition, and not doing what it is supposed to do. Try with nil error in retriever.SSM instead.

Comment: If I change err: to nil in retriever.SSM, I'll get a nil pointer deference panic. I checked the value of "req" when passing in the mock value, but nothing comes through.

Comment: Where do you get the panic?

Comment: Panic occurs in the `GetSSMValue()` function at 
`SSMValue := *req.Parameter.Value`

Comment: That's got nothing to do with err. When err is non-nil, your code returns before that statement. When you made err nil, now the code passes the error check, but self.SSM.GetParameter returned nil (i.e. req is nil), or req.Parameter is nil, or req.Parameter.Value is nil.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how do I have the test return the mocked output of `outputParameter` so that `SSMValue` would be "MyTestOutput"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202677/discussion-between-theorangeremix-and-burak-serdar).

Answer (score 1):

Actually everything was right, you just need add 1 line of code to initialise output.Parameter: `output.Parameter = &ssm.Parameter{Value: aws.String("MyTestOutput")}`

And you func must looks like this:

```
func (sp *mockSSM) GetParameter(input *ssm.GetParameterInput) (*ssm.GetParameterOutput, error) {
    output := new(ssm.GetParameterOutput)
    output.Parameter = &ssm.Parameter{Value: aws.String("MyTestOutput")}
    return output, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to insert the mocked output inside the `GetParameter()` function in the test module. This seems to work:

```
func (sp *mockSSM) GetParameter(input *ssm.GetParameterInput) (*ssm.GetParameterOutput, error) {
        // Defines actual value that is received in the response
        output := &ssm.GetParameterOutput{
                Parameter: &ssm.Parameter{
                        Type: aws.String("String"),
                        Value: aws.String("MyTestOutput"),
                },
        }
        return output, nil

}
```